# Huge concentrations of + singular or plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm reading George Orwell's *You and the Atomic Bomb*, and I'm wondering why he says 'huge concentrations of **industrial plant**'. I expected 'industrial plants'.

Here's the sentence:

> The one thing that might reverse it is the discovery of a weapon — or, to put it more broadly, of a method of fighting — not dependent on huge concentrations of industrial plant.

Thanks!

Comment: So, he’s using it as a non-count noun.

Answer (score 3):

From *Lexico*:

> plant
>
> [mass noun]
>
> Machinery used in an industrial or manufacturing process.
>
> ‘*inadequate investment in new plant*’

He's not referring to the place or facility where production takes place but the ***machinery***.

> *huge concentrations of industrial **machinery***